# How do I display retrieved data in CakePHP 3.0?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've used CakePHP 2.0 for quite a while, and I'm trying to migrate to 3.0.  Most of it is fine, but I'm confused by how to retrieve data from a table and show it in a view.

Let's say my database contains menus and menuitems. Each Menu can have many Menuitems (each Menuitem record has field menu_id).

So, in CakePHP 2.0 I would have had the following:

```
Model:
Menu hasMany Menuitem

Controller:
$this->set->recursive = 1;
$menu = $this->Menu->findById($menuid);

View:
foreach($menu['Menuitem'] as $item) {
 ... display item ...
}
```

In Cake 3.0 I'm trying to replicate this.  So, I have:

```
In Model/Table/MenusTable.php:
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasMany('Menuitems', [
                        'sort' => ['Menuitems.order' => 'ASC']
        ]);
    }

In Controller:
$menus= TableRegistry::get('Menus');
$query = $menus->find('all')
                    ->contain(['Menuitems');
$menulist= $query->toArray();
$this->set(compact('menulist'));
```

How do I now display this in the view?

If I try:

```
foreach($menu['Menuitem'] as $item)
```

then I get the error "Undefined index: Menuitem".

Then I tried `$menu.menuitems` and `$menu->menuitems` but those didn't work either.  Where am I going wrong?

### Edit

If I do `debug($menulist)` I get the following:

```
(int) 0 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {
    'id' => (int) 1,
    'name' => 'Main',
    'menuitems' => [
        (int) 0 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

            'id' => (int) 1,
            'subsite_id' => (int) 1,
            'page_id' => (int) 1,
            'parentmenuitem_id' => null,
            'nav_order' => (int) 1,
            'nav_width' => null,
            'children' => [],
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Menuitems'

        },
        (int) 1 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

            'id' => (int) 2,
            'subsite_id' => (int) 1,
            'page_id' => (int) 2,
            'parentmenuitem_id' => null,
            'nav_order' => (int) 2,
            'nav_width' => null,
            'children' => [
                (int) 0 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

                    'id' => (int) 9,
                    'subsite_id' => (int) 1,
                    'page_id' => (int) 9,
                    'parentmenuitem_id' => (int) 2,
                    'nav_order' => (int) 1,
                    'nav_width' => null,
                    '[new]' => false,
                    '[accessible]' => [
                        '*' => true
                    ],
                    '[dirty]' => [],
                    '[original]' => [],
                    '[virtual]' => [],
                    '[errors]' => [],
                    '[invalid]' => [],
                    '[repository]' => 'Children'

                },
                (int) 1 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

                    'id' => (int) 10,
                    'subsite_id' => (int) 1,
                    'page_id' => (int) 13,
                    'parentmenuitem_id' => (int) 2,
                    'nav_order' => (int) 2,
                    'nav_width' => null,
                    '[new]' => false,
                    '[accessible]' => [
                        '*' => true
                    ],
                    '[dirty]' => [],
                    '[original]' => [],
                    '[virtual]' => [],
                    '[errors]' => [],
                    '[invalid]' => [],
                    '[repository]' => 'Children'

                },
                (int) 2 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

                    'id' => (int) 11,
                    'subsite_id' => (int) 1,
                    'page_id' => (int) 14,
                    'parentmenuitem_id' => (int) 2,
                    'nav_order' => (int) 3,
                    'nav_width' => null,
                    '[new]' => false,
                    '[accessible]' => [
                        '*' => true
                    ],
                    '[dirty]' => [],
                    '[original]' => [],
                    '[virtual]' => [],
                    '[errors]' => [],
                    '[invalid]' => [],
                    '[repository]' => 'Children'

                }
            ],
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Menuitems'

        },
    ],
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Subsites'

}
]
```

Comment: shouldnt it be @menulist instead of $menu and then in your view var_dump $menulist and see what it is

Comment: Sorry, yes, I do have $menulist, I mistyped above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis of what ('menulist') variable you have set , your foreach should look like:

```
foreach($menulist->Menuitems as $item)
{
  // your logic here
}
```

Just debug your set variable and see how the data are coming , sometimes that might come differently depending on your query.

Comment: Forgot to reply at the time, but this helped, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What does your returned data look like? You should check the variable using either `debug($menulist)` or look at the set view variables in debugkit.

In CakePHP 3 contained models should show in your data as a lowercase snake cased item (not the model alias like in CakePHP 2) and as the plural form for `hasMany` associations, so I would expect your case to be something like this:-

```
foreach ($menulist['menuitems'] as $item):
    // Output your menu item
endforeach;
```

Comment: If there is no capital letter in the modelname (apart from the initial one) there won't be a _ in the index name. The example clearly shows Menuitems, not MenuItems.

Comment: @JvO well spotted, I've updated my answer accordingly.